# Can C++ be wrapped around a Ruby C extension?

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, wrapper

This is something that's more than likely popped up in the past and I've found some good resources and descriptions of this on the web but nothing has been very definitive. Is there a way to wrap C++ around a C Ruby extension so that C++ and Ruby can "communicate"? The simple reason for asking this is because that while C extensions in Ruby can behave significantly faster in large scale scenarios than Ruby by itself, C++ can perform yet faster that C. The other reason is that a lot of people seem to be learning C++ as opposed to C, and are more familiar with it. Granted if you're a C++ professional, then C will be a piece of cake to learn.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There should be no problem if you declare your C++ functions as `extern "C"`. But for the reasons to do this, I think you are completely mistaken. There is no reason at all that C++ be "faster" (in whatever meaning you give to that term) than C. This is just one of the urban myths. In the contrary, if you don't take care you easily have more indirections in C++ and thus more overhead. And you are also mistaken when thinking C++ professonals will as such "easily" write good C code. These are two different languages with each their own particularities.

Comment: Well hey I'm not trying to talk about or primarily convey that efficiency is what I'm interested in or step on anyones toes. I'm just curious if it's possible! :)

Comment: Communicate? Hm.. I'd make ruby `tcp` server and c++ tcp client socket or vice versa. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you have to be careful with many things. In particular exceptions.

Ruby handles exceptions with setjmp/longjmp. This makes the stack any C++ function involved be freed without calling any local destructor at all. As a workaround you would have to rescue from all possible call that can possibly raise errors, free your stack yourself (possibly using an c++ exception) and raise them again.

Similarly there are many calls in the c++ stdlib that can throw exceptions (even `new` operators), you can't let them go into ruby world or something will crash deadly. You must catch them all and raise them as ruby exceptions.

This game of conversion will likely slowdown your code and make the interface hard to write and understand. There are probably other problems too. Exposing a class with its inheritance chain can be tricky.

Take a look at [rice](http://rice.rubyforge.org/). It might help you.

Comment: Very cool! I realized that a surplus of things can go wrong when interacting doing something like this, which is why I wasn't trying to imply that doing this would be for performance enhancements. Rice was actually something I ran into while researching this, and is what I thought @Jens Gustedt was referring to when recommending the `extern 'C'` option.